What is the function of this mechanism?
I saw this (custom?) mechanism attached to a gate in Stockholm, Sweden. Maybe I'm being obtuse, but I can't discern what it's supposed to do. Count the number of times the gate is opened? Is it just a soft-closing mechanism of some kind?



So, what moves? did you try it? what angle does the gate move through? is there an override? Or did you just take the photo? actually using it may be better...

And is that on the hinge side or the latch side?

I couldn't try it; the gates were locked. It was a set of two gates, opening inwards I assume. At a guess, it's the gate on the left that typically gets pushed inward to open, and the gate on the right with the cylinder and vertical bar has a "slam plate" on it.

where is it on Google maps?

OK, I have identified the location, which is actually in Stockholm (my bad). I have added a StreetView image to the question.

The gate is on Google street view here.

my guess is that pressing the top down,  raises the plunger on the bottom

The gate is in front of what looks to be an elementary school.  Looking at the gate a bit, it appears that it will swing both ways but it not supposed to open out.  There is also a rusty looking piece of metal below the (original) lock/latch that will keep the gate from opening outwards.  All historical pictures from Google street-view show the gate closed.  Only the current picture from July 2024 shows the gate open and open outwards.
As observed by @ratchetfreak, the mechanism latches the gate, you have to pick up the inner cylinder to open the gate.  When it closes, the one way clutch allows the mechanism to rotate and latch closed.

Maybe the purpose of the tall cylinder is to put the mechanism out of reach of kids. You would need to reach up to 1.8 m or so to unlatch the gate.

it might be a automatic lock or latch but engineered to minimize damage to the old (probably antique and historically protected) gate. The original latch mechanism is very likely completely rusted solid and impossible to repair without destroying large parts of the gate.
The wheel would have a one-way clutch/ratchet to only allow rotation in one way. When the gat swings closed the wheel would engage the round piston and then rotate and latch.
Then to open the gate you would need to lift that inner cylinder that engages with the wheel. This would be done by twisting or lifting the top part of the cylinder
The blue plate on the right probably has a description of why the gate is protected and where the mechanism came from.

It all seems rather over-engineered when a hinged hoop could do the job. I can't figure out why there are five spokes.

If the gate were "antique and historically protected," why would they have bolted on such a big, ugly and incongruous (aluminum on an iron gate) mechanism?

Historical Google Street-view shows that the blue sign next to the gate was added between July 2011 and May 2014, before the mechanism was added to the gate.  The mechanism in question was added between May 2014 and July 2017

@user1683793 it does look over engineered for what it should do, but there are only 4 bolts holding it to the gate. But there might have been certain design criteria that prohibited a simpler more elegant solution.
